# How to translate from Sub Domain to RESTful urls in ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wonder what options I have in MVC Routing that can redirect/translate the incoming requests to the sub-domain urls and redirect them to the new RESTful scheme.

```
OLD
http://conv.mc.siteexample.com/v01/?token=AB03959BM23DFC3
http://click.mc.siteexample.com/?cd=1&sd=828&dd=1


NEW
http://siteexample.com/api/uri/conv/?token=AB03959BM23DFC3
http://siteexample.com/api/uri/click/?cd=1&sd=828&dd=1
```

*Also a side note that I am actually using MVC WebAPI Routing, but I am sure that this is not important.*

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Url Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in IIS. Then inside your Web API application you would simply use the standard routing.

Comment: Thanks, but this is an Azure web role and I have no control over IIS

Comment: If you have no control over IIS, how do you expect to remove the subdomain and leave only the TLD?

Comment: I define the URL endpoints in Azure cloud project ServiceDefinition.csdef configuration file.

Comment: Whatever is present in ServiceDefinition.csdef, gets translated into IIS settings by the deployment process.

Comment: You have some `v01` in your OLD url which disappears in the NEW url. What's the rule for it? Also do you want a redirect or rewrite?

Comment: v01 is omitted as there is no need for it.

Comment: Alright, but what if the original url was for example `/v01/foo/bar`? Do you want to omit only the `v01` or the entire path? What's the rule?

Comment: V01, V02 ... all go to the same /api/uri/conv/

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How should the following url be translated to a new: `http://conv.mc.siteexample.com/v01/foo/bar/baz?token=AB03959BM23DFC3`. Also you didn't answer my second question: do you want a redirect or a rewrite?

Comment: Yes sorry, it will translate to http://siteexample.com/api/uri/conv/?token=AB03959BM23DFC3